# When to unregister KVO observation of Operation isFinished

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, nsoperation

In this simple code (Xcode 8.3), I create an Operation subclass instance, register for KVO observation of its `isFinished` property, and launch the operation by adding it to my queue:

```
class MyOperation : Operation {
    override func main() {
        print("starting")
        print("finishing")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let q = OperationQueue()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let op = MyOperation()
        op.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(MyOperation.isFinished), options: [], context: nil)
        self.q.addOperation(op)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("Observed \(keyPath)")
        if let op = object as? Operation {
            op.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(MyOperation.isFinished))
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have an implementation of `observeValue(forKeyPath...`, of course, and my plan was to call `removeObserver(forKeyPath...` there.

The problem is that my app crashes with "MyOperation was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it". We print "starting" and "finishing" but we never print "Observed"; the operation goes out of existence *before* I get my KVO notification.

This seems like a catch-22. If I can't remove the observer by observing `isFinished`, when am I supposed to do it? [I can work around this issue by adding to MyOperation my own KVO-observable property that I set at the end of `main`. But the notion that I should have to do this is very odd; isn't this exactly why `isFinished` is observable, so that I can do what I'm trying to here?]

Comment: Could it be the issue mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2109/_index.html? – "Similar problems can arise when you use key-value observing (KVO) to observe the isFinished property of an NSOperation. While KVO does not retain either the observer or the observee, it's still possible that, even if you remove the observer in your -viewWillDisappear: method, a KVO notification might already be in flight for your object. If that happens, the thread running the notification could end up calling a deallocated object!"

Comment: @MartinR That section of the note is talking about the danger that `self` (the observer) might go out of existence, so the KVO notification might be sent to a nonexistent object. That's the _opposite_ of my problem; my problem is that the operation (the observand) is going out of existence without sending me my KVO notification. `self` is the root view controller and is going nowhere.

Comment: Is there any usefulness to mention that I tried it and I am able to see: `starting finishing Observed Optional("isFinished")`? my app does *not* crashes. I'm using xcode 8.2, I hope that I understood what's the case...

Comment: @AhmadF If you are seeing that result and not crashing, in Xcode 8.2, that suggests that this might be (incredibly) a new bug in Xcode 8.3. I will try it on my other machine (which still has Xcode 8.2) and see if I can confirm. I'll let you know what I find out. Thanks!

Comment: @AhmadF You're absolutely right. I invite you to enter as an answer the fact that you tried this in Xcode 8.2 and that all three `print` statements print and we don't crash, and suggesting that this might be a bug (or at least new behavior) in Xcode 8.3. And I will accept that answer. Thank you so much! (And I will also file a bug report with Apple.)

Comment: Reported to Apple as radar 31485465.

Comment: Seriously I'm so glad to help, that made my day (almost can't believe that I got an acceptance for my answer from you!). Anyway, could you please provide a link for the reported bug? In fact I am not familiar with "Apple radar", what I know it the Swift one "bugs.swift.org/".

Comment: @AhmadF I am assuming that this is a bug in Cocoa (Foundation), not Swift. Therefore it is reported at https://bugreport.apple.com. This is a really terrible bugbase; you cannot see other people's reported bugs! However, it is useful to tell people that you have reported something as a bug and to provide the "radar" number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing the exact same given code snippet on *Xcode 8.2*, it worked as it should, the console shows:

```
starting
finishing
Observed Optional("isFinished")
```

It seems that the reason of the issue is testing it on *Xcode 8.3*, probably it is a bug -or it might be a new behavior-. However, I would suggest to report it as a bug.

Comment: Okay, it turns out that the bug is not a Cocoa Foundation bug — it's a Swift language bug involving `#keyPath`. The workaround is to write `op.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "isFinished", options: [], context: nil)` using a literal string instead.

Comment: Here's the Swift bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4397 I submitted mine too, but it was (rightly) marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @matt But what is the reason of: we should implement it as `forKeyPath: "isFinished"` instead of `#keyPath(MyOperation.isFinished)`? the case seems to me similar to working with `#selector`.

Comment: But that's exactly the bug. `forKeyPath: #keyPath(MyOperation.isFinished)` in Swift 3.0 equates to `forKeyPath: "isFinished"`, so it works. But in Swift 3.1 it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Apple changed `#keyPath` behavior in Swift 3.1 ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html)). Currently `#keyPath(isFinished)` returns `"finished"`, it used to return `"isFinished"`, and **that was a bug**. Here is the explanation as it can easily get confusing when using `KVO` and `Operation` class.

---

When you register an object for KVO notifications

```
textView.addObserver(self,
                     forKeyPath: #keyPath(UITextView.isEditable),
                     options: [.new, .old],
                     context: nil)
```

Foundation provides it (`textView`) with new setter implementation that calls `willChangeValue(forKey:)` and `didChangeValue(forKey:)` ([this is done via isa-swizzling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002307-BAJEAIEE)). The key that is passed to those methods is not getter (`isEditable`) not setter(`setEditable:`) but property name (`editable`).

```
@property(nonatomic,getter=isEditable) BOOL editable
```

This is why it is expected to receive `editable` from `#keyPath(UITextView.isEditable)`.

---

Although Operation class has properties defined ad follows

```
@property (readonly, getter=isExecuting) BOOL executing;
@property (readonly, getter=isFinished) BOOL finished;
```

It expects to observe notifications for `isFinished` and `isExecuting` keys.

> Upon completion or cancellation of its task, your concurrent operation object must generate KVO notifications for both the isExecuting and isFinished key paths to mark the final change of state for your operation

This forces us to use literal strings when posting those notifications.

IMHO this is a mistake made years ago which is really hard to recover from without breaking existing code.

Comment: Yes, I know all that.